# Sort array by enum order and not value

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I would like to order a `Array` of object, where object contain a enum properties.

```
export enum MyEnum {
  FIXTERM1W = 'FIXTERM_1W',
  FIXTERM2W = 'FIXTERM_2W',
  FIXTERM1M = 'FIXTERM_1M',
  FIXTERM2M = 'FIXTERM_2M',
  FIXTERM3M = 'FIXTERM_3M',
  FIXTERM6M = 'FIXTERM_6M',
  FIXTERM1Y = 'FIXTERM_1Y',
  FIXTERMDEFAULT = 'FIXTERM_DEFAULT',
  FIXTERMWA = 'FIXTERM_WA',
  ONCALL24H = 'ONCALL_24H',
  ONCALL48H = 'ONCALL_48H',
  ONCALLWA = 'ONCALL_WA'
};
```

In my array `_myvalue` I have list of `myobject`, each `myobject` contain a properties code of type `MyEnum`  :

```
get xxx(): (Yyyy) {
    if (this._myvalue && this._myvalue.myobject && this._myvalue.myobject.length > 0) {
      this._myvalue.myobject = sortBy(this._myvalue.myobject,
        [function (o: any): any {
          return o.code;
        }]);
    }
    return this._myvalue;
}
```

The problem is that I get the array order by enum name :

1. 1W
2. 1M
3. 1Y
4. ...

Instead of :

1. 1W
2. 2W
3. 1M
4. ...

How I can order my array by the "order" of my enum ? and not a alphabetical order ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    const order = [];
    for (let key in MyEnum) {
          order.push(key);
    }
    const newArray = myArray.sort((a, b) => {
          const index1 = order.findIndex(key => MyEnum[key] === a.code);
          const index2 = order.findIndex(key => MyEnum[key] === b.code);
          return index1 - index2;
    });
```

This will sort your array, in the order keys are stored in MyEnum.

Answer (score 0):

You could use :

```
MyObject.sort((a, b) => Object.values(MyEnum).indexOf(a.code) - Object.values(MyEnum).indexOf(b.code))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).